# NO_PUBKEY for apt.releases.hashicorp.com in apt

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, apt, gpg-signature

When running `sudo apt update`, I am presented with the following error:

```
Err:4 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal InRelease                                                                               
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AA16FCBCA621E701
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Vagrant specifically is off topic. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Comment: The official unstructions to update the public gpg key (incl. "verifying" the fingerprint) can be found here: https://www.hashicorp.com/official-packaging-guide

Answer (score 13):

Remove the exiting Hashicorp files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and then follow the [official guide](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/announcing-the-hashicorp-linux-repository):

```
sudo -s
wget -O- https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg |
    gpg --dearmor > /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg

echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list
apt update
```

Answer (score 0):

The GPG key is outdated or missing.

Run this code to remove the outdated key `sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg`

And this to obtain the current key: `curl https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | gpg --dearmor > /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg`

I had the run that last one under root (`sudo -s`), as I couldn't get sudo to play ball with the pipe character. Not really sure why

Comment: `curl https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg` takes care of the piping, but does not fix the overall problem

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is with the sources.list file being used.  Ultimately it links to a keyring, which doesn't contain key `AA16FCBCA621E701`.

In my case this was the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list`

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/terraform-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com jammy main
```

The above notes (thank you MacroMan), led me to this (which creates a new, valid hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg, his original instructions don't work unless you're running as `su - root`, which I never do)

```
curl https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg
```

With the new keyring, edit the above file to replace `terraform-archive-keyring.gpg` with `hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg` and `sudo apt-get update` should run without errors.

Alternatively (I didn't run this, but someone might find it useful, as it recreates the sources.list using `sudo tee`, so doesnt need to be run as root, as `>` does)

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee  etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list
```